# Handling ActionResult from inside the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Describing my scenario will be the best way to describe what I'm trying to achieve. I'm looking for a cleaner solution, if it exists at all.

We have content that would like to lock. I abstracted the unlocking models because we could have different types. It could be a Redirect or rendered partial view or something else they could come up in the future, so I decided to try returning an ActionResult.

```
public abstract class AContentUnlocker
{
    public abstract ActionResult GetUnlockActionResult();
}

public class RedirectUnlocker : AContentUnlocker
{
    public override ActionResult GetUnlockActionResult()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://www.url1.com?returnUrl=mywebsiteagain");
    }
}

public class PartialViewUnlocker: AContentUnlocker
{

    public override ActionResult GetUnlockActionResult()
    {
        PartialViewResult view = new PartialViewResult();
        view.ViewName = "_PartialViewToUnlock";
        return view;
    }
}
```

My Content would be represented in a model with the proper Unlocking Mechanism

```
public class MyContent
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public AContentUnlocker ContentUnlocker { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I would simply return my desired Content with the proper unlocking mechanism set.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyContent myContent = new MyContent() { 
        Description = "Content 1", 
        ContentUnlocker = new PartialViewUnlocker() 
    }; 

    return View(myContent);
}
```

In my index View, I would then Execute the ActionResult.

```
@{
   Model.ContentUnlocker.GetUnlockActionResult().ExecuteResult(this.ViewContext);
}

return View(myContent);
```

The Redirect ActionResult works fine.
My problem is that with the Partial View Action Results, given the execution cycle of MVC, the partial view is rendered before the controller view. So I'm getting something like:

```
<!-- html of the partial view rendered -->
<div> blah blah </div>

<!-- html of the parent view -->
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body> blah   .... </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure it's possible, but is there a way to execute my ActionResult the same way Html.RenderPartial would?